# If we can require a particular domain, can we require a particular path?

Tags: discussion, policy

### Background

Following on from [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13621/58974) where it was decided that, as we define languages by their implementation, JavaScript solutions could include a requirement that they be run under a specific domain. This allows us to use, for example, `/questions/[id]?site=codegolf` instead of `//api.stackexchange.com/questions/[id]?site=codegolf` to save a few bytes.

In a recent solution I took this a (small) step further, requiring that it be run at the root level of `api.stackexchange.com` and using `questions/[id]?site=codegolf` to save another byte.

### Proposal

But that then got me to thinking: if we can require a specific domain then we could, by extension, be able to require a specific *path*, with the above example becoming simply `[id]/?site=codegolf` if run from `api.stackexchange.com/questions/`.

Personally, I *feel* that it's pushing things too far but couldn't come up with a legitimate argument against allowing it so decided to post this question to garner some thoughts from the community and, hopefully, reach a consensus on it.

Comment: I think it should work similar to running from a custom directory, but I can't remember how that works.

Comment: Really, this should be a comment on the linked question, or a separate answer outlining the problems with accepting the current answer - the question is basically the same. I for one have upvoted the 'second' answer, seeing how problematic an exact definition of the 'first' answer is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can JS answers require the code to be run at a certain domain?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13621/can-js-answers-require-the-code-to-be-run-at-a-certain-domain)

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate. This question is a follow-up to that question that asks if full paths can be specified instead of only a domain. The proposed duplicate is even linked to in the question.

Comment: This probably applies to running locally too, e.g. a bash script that only works if your current directory is /usr ?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be allowed to specify a path that's not, say, on a static sitemap. Otherwise every answer becomes `eval(base64decode(window.location.pathname[5,5432])))`

Comment: @histocrat Why use `.pathname` when you can use `.search`?